# recognizing a link in an email

Tags: iphone

Is there a mechanism where I can identify a string in an email, say a order number, and have it route to my iPhone application?  I know that base types do this, but not sure if I can create a new type for my app.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to create email message programmatically and add link in it?

Comment: I am looking to associate my application with a link in an email.  For example, I can send you and email on your phone that would have a link to an order number.  Instead of that link opening safari on the phone, I want it to open my app for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom URL type through your app (say orderNum://)

Then, if you include a link in the email, say orderNum://1234567890

if the user clicks it, it will open your app, and you will be able to get the data it sent you.

See the LaunchMe example: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/LaunchMe/Introduction/Intro.html